# From Org code block on *nix run (Power-)Shell (scripts) on MS Windows via SSH

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, shell, ssh, linux

To better integrate my Windows DevOps into Emacs Org-mode, I'd like to use my local emacs as an IDE for a remote Powershell.

[SSH was easily setup](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH), from Linux shell `ssh` I can successfully login to a `powershell` [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) shell as a domain user, and run commands, without password, using keys. Non-ASCII characters like 'é' work, and <kbd>TAB</kbd> works as usual in `cmd` and `powershell`.

I routinely run code blocks on Linux systems via SSH, so I tried:

```
#+NAME: PSH-Test
#+HEADER: :dir "/ssh:MyWinPC:~/"
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
  ipconfig
#+END_SRC
```

When I run the above, I get queried for my remote password, and then I get a message

> Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on MyWinPC

Emacs then hangs until I press C-g.

In `*scratch*` I then executed `(setq tramp-verbose 10)`, and retried. In the debug output buffer I could see my remote prompt, so login seems to have worked, and there was a message indicating, that `/bin/sh` could not be loaded. So I am assuming this to be the/a problem.

Do I need `winexe`, If i can successfully `ssh`?

Using `sh`, `shell`, or `powershell` as code block language makes no difference.
I installed a package for powershell from the package manager.

So, How do I correctly call/execute PowerShell/CMD commands/scripts from linux emacs org-mode code blocks on remote Windows 7+ Hosts via SSH?

Note: In the meantime I use the workaround of wrapping all windows devops scripts into a linux shell block, that does `ssh` as first step, but that feels ugly.

Comment: According to org-mode user manual, language abbreviation should be "sh" for shell, so  ```#+BEGIN_SRC sh```. Take care you need to ```(require 'ob-shell)```  in your configuration, if your org version is >8.2

Comment: @Ian: in the same document, and others, I have shell-blocks and blocks for other languages as well, that i can successfully execute, so thank you for your suggestion, but I think, my problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If you ssh directly, without emacs, into MyWinPC do you get a shell?

Comment: @Melioratus Thx for the +1. No, I did not figure this out, and I do not currently manage windows hosts. But it will happen again soon, so I will be trying to figure this one out. At the time, i was able to log into my windows hosts from shell level into shell level, without password. At the time i choose wrapping my windows powershell in linux scripts, that ssh as first step. I will edit the post to make this clearer. Feel free to mark this comment as obsolete when seen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I suspect doing Literate DevOps on Windows would be really useful for the community. I wonder if your issue was caused by the environment on windows. My guess is that the `SRC` block stalled creating the temporary script on the windows filesystem. Also I wonder if adding  `:session session-name` header to your `SRC` block would provide additional debug output  in a buffer named session-name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone is still interested. Her is an solution, that is a bit of a hack, but works:

```
#+NAME: Powershell-Test
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results value verbatim
 ssh Win powershell -nologo << \.
Get-NetAdapter
.
#+END_SRC
```

It uses HEREDOC redirected to powershell over ssh.